# Apache links not being sent to correct port

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, vagrant, lamp

I have vagrant up and running, forwarding port 80 -> 8080. The PHP project is being served if I navigate to `localhost:8080`. However, all the links are being to sent to `localhost`, which doesn't work since my local machine isn't serving the project. I need the link to be `localhost:8080/xxxxxx`.

I believe I need to add a rule to `.htaccess`, but I'm not exactly sure what I need to add. Any help would be appreciated, and if I should move this to serverfault or superuser please let me know.

Comment: This sounds more like an issue with the application thinking that it needs to build links with "localhost" rather than "localhost:8080". Are you running a framework?

Comment: Yes, Drupal. This is my first project on a new team and I'm new to the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `/sites/default/settings.php` Drupal file, and change the `$base_url` variable to:

```
$base_url = 'http://localhost:8080'; // NO trailing slash!
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main Joomla .htaccess insert this rule as **very first rule**:

```
# this line might be already there
RewriteEngine On

# if port in request is not 8080 then redirect to 8080
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=8080
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=302,L]
```